# How can I give myself an infinite amount of items for a rapid-fire dispenser?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-mods

I've been messing around on Minecraft with Not Enough Items, trying to get an ∞ amount of items so that I can make a rapidly-firing dispenser that always shoots and doesn't run out of ammo. I mean when people have like 111 spawn eggs or something in their inventory.

I know how to make a redstone clock. But I try to get an ∞ amount of fire charges, it says in chat it gave me an ∞ amount of fire charges, but I don't have it in my inventory.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to get an "infinite stack" of anything would be to set up a clock that drops an item, constantly. You can't hold an "infinite" stack of anything in Minecraft.

So, set up a command block to drop a fire charge in a certain location, then hook it up to a red-stone clock. Then, set up a hopper beneath that location, and feed it into your dispenser.

Comment: I need to edit my comment... I meant, in Not Enough Items when you get a infinite amount of items like in videos when people have 111 wood planks or something. Sorry for wording it wrong. Thanks by the way

Comment: @rager the issue is that this doesn't work when you place it in a storage location, like a dropper. This is only used as a way of not having to jump in and out of creative constantly.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out now. Thanks Ben. With your answer, I made my own answer. A command block hooked up to a clock does

```
/summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:fire_charge",Count:1}}
```

and the item that gets summoned drops into a hopper into a dispenser hooked up to a clock. I now have an infinite dispenser I can use for my map. Thanks!

Comment: That is exactly what Ben wrote. You can mark his answer as accepted.

Comment: Sorry for being a noob at this, Fabian. I haven't touched arqade in a while. I only got an account for one question.

Comment: I may have said the same thing, but I did it a different way as what he said :I It does the same thing as what he said, if that makes sense.

Comment: @rager that's exactly what I had suggested, lol. I just didn't add the command line itself.

Comment: Sorry for being a noob at this, Ben. I haven't touched arqade in a while. I only got an account for one question.   (A.K.A The first question I asked about colored wool on player head)